# a network related or instance-specific error 26

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, connection-string

In random I get following error when my client app want to get connect to db
[image]

and the solution is to restart sqlbrowser in server and every thing works fine ,but in random it happens again and again.
note : instance name , server name or IP , remote connection accept , firewall all are correct and checked a lot , just by restarting sqlbrowser it works again.

following is my connection string.
[image]

I tracked sql log but not very clear to me as I am beginner in sql , please help me on this I am going sick because of this random error !!!!!!
[image]

Comment: Check application error logs, system error logs in eventviewer. Check for DB logs. Try creating differebnt port than default SQL port and try to connect your DB.

Comment: I put my db sql log in above image ! could you check it out and let me know if there is any problem?! @PareshJ

Comment: You can avoid the dependency on the SQL Browser service by specifying the actual port number instead of instance name in the connection string (i.e. Data Source=Server02,56761).  This is just an interim solution until you find the root cause of the SQL Browser service problem.

Comment: I will check it out and report the result dear @DanGuzman

Comment: @DanGuzman your solution didn't worked for me !!!!

Comment: @franchesco_totti, can you establish a connection with the port specification, or is it that you are still getting intermittent errors?  If you can't establish a connection at all, verify the port number is correct.  Also, do the intermittent connection problems coincide with the "server resumed execution..." messages in the log?

Comment: @DanGuzman yes , intermittent connection problems coincide with the "server resumed execution..." messages in the log.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the intermittent connection problems are due to the lag when SQL Express instance reawakens after going idle since there is a strong correlation.  This lag is normally not so severe as to cause connection timeouts but there could be other processes running on the same server besides SQL Server competing for limited memory resources and thus prolong the time it takes for SQL Express to resume normal operation.  However, I wouldn't expect restarting the SQL Browser service to remediate the issue as you reported, especially if a port number if specified in the connection string instead of the instance name.

To prevent SQL Express from going idle, periodically connect to the instance.  One method to do this is with a repeating Windows Task scheduler job that runs the Powershell command below:

```
powershell -Command "$c = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(\"Data Source=server01,56761;Initial Catalog=OxygenDB;User Id=youruser;Password=yourpassword\"); $c.Open(); $c.Close();"
```

Also, you can improve responsiveness by turning off the database auto close option with the following T-SQL command:

```
ALTER DATABASE OxygenDB SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;
```

Comment: Actually ,I have done AUTO CLOSE OFF before but the problem still exist

Comment: @franchescototti, I did not mean to imply that AUTO_CLOSE was the reason for your problem, only that it may improve response time.  You need to perform some regular activity to prevent the instance from going idle.